# Answers I don't understand and/or answers that are questions/riddles/koans

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, flagging

[Fex. I asked a question about self as verb, and one of the answers was really not an answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/12931/254).

The "answer" was:

> **Self as noun or action/verb?**
>
> Is mirage is a noun or action?
>   Is rainbow is a noun or action?
>
> Is Dress(Not cloth) is a noun(a thing) or concept?
>   Is person is a noun or concept?

If I wanted a riddle or questions back I would have asked for it. I can't see how asking questions back is useful.

I don't like to get into quarrels with or offend other users, so I'd like to know what happens if I flag answers.

Comment: It can be useful, it can be very very useful, some questions like that haunted me for months and then when the aha moment came it was much more powerful and deep than any detailed explanation might have given me, for I would not really understand it. What kind of answer you need at a time is individual I guess, but http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/277/7587 approach with the spoiler tag would have given everybody what they were looking for. Maybe that is what we're looking for?

Comment: When you ask a question are the answers just for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Help Center there are [*guidelines*](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for how to write a good answer. These can be taken into account when evaluating the quality of an answer.

If one decides to flag an answer, there are several possibilities. Take a look at the picture below. This is the menu one will see when pressing the *flag* button. When a post has been flagged then the site-moderators handle it from there. A moderator have several options, some of them are to *edit the post, delete it, leave a comment to the author*.

Flagging is anonymous for other users, only moderators can see who have flagged a post.

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask again, if you need more info.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Concept,

If you are up to *mentally* dispraise something, you should consider [this (Avannaraha Sutta: Dispraise)](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.083.bodh_en.html).

If you are up to verbally dispraise something (and 'flagging' is probably generally assumed as such), you should consider "this (sutta about Dispraise)" too.

If a moderator is up to bodily destroy something, thinking "that has been dispraised, that is not good for our credits", he too should consider "this (about Dispraise)".

Having dispraised mentally and seen that this was wrong, you should be ashamed about your way and put an effort to abstain from it. Having dispraised verbally (flagged), and seen that this was wrong, you should confess it to a [admirable friend](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-ditthi/kalyanamittata.html) and look for ways to undo your "pitfall" by addressing the mod.

If the moderator was following your hint blindly, that your action has been fulfilled as well and you should confess it and try to remove an eventual "pitfall" or to reconstruct the bridge over a "pitfall" for others.

As for the moderator himself (or herself), it's actually the same: whether he/she did it for [this or that purpose](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.097.than_en.html), "this (sutta about Dispraise)" still fits.

---

Regard the answer you quoted, this is actually a perfect answer, since "Self" is actually a deed (often called I-making by the Buddha), a deed by thought that make it to a "Subject or Object" (concept of reality) - as it is with the other samples as well - what someone could have found (or has been able to find) out for him or her self with this perfect bridge out of a thicket of wrong views. But if somebody simply stays on the level of certain conventions, does not loosen ones grasps before, then such an explaining (like I did here for your sample) might be accepted broadly but stay for another time just an conventional view and has less change to encourage one self what this circle of sequence in making things to something lasting, a noun, is all about and so does one fail to understand and being released.

But "*Having directly known the extent of designation and the extent of the objects of designation, the extent of expression and the extent of the objects of expression, the extent of description and the extent of the objects of description, the extent of discernment and the extent of the objects of discernment, the extent to which the cycle revolves: Having directly known that, the reader is released. [To say that,] 'The reader released, having directly known that, does not see, does not know is his opinion,' that would be mistaken*. ([Delineations of a Self](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/dn/dn.15.0.than_en.html))

**As it is in the midst of Dhamma and not just a "we"-arguing, Atma suggests to move it into the "beta" area.**

*(Note: this answer has not been given with the agreement to be means of trade or the purpose of/for trade and/or keep people trapped and bound. How you handle it lies in your sphere, but does not excuse the deed here either.) Credits in regard of grammer and spelling goes to Upasaka Chris and the moderator team. Sadhu!*

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It's all right, we'll get along

Comment: We? Are you even sure about your self? Mr @Mr.Concept Concept. And you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

#### I don't like to get into quarrels with or offend other users

Welcome. :-)

I hope most other users here are that way too.

A related topic is [Posting comments to answers](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1793/254).

#### ..., so I'd like to know what happens if I flag answers.

Related topics:

- [Should this 'zen type' answer be deleted?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1561/254)
- [Moderating answers which don't answer the question?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1676/254)

In summary, it depends on whether people (including you) perceive it as a useful answer.

If you **downvote** an answer, people will see that *someone* downvoted it but they won't know who (won't know it was you).

A curious person can look at your total "Votes Cast" on your user profile (and see how many times you've up- and down-voted in total), but people can't associate individual votes with specific topics.

If you **flag** an answer then *moderators* will know you flagged it, but that's confidential (i.e. moderators won't tell other users about any flags you raise).

In any case (whether or not anyone flags), moderators may or may not choose to delete an answer (depending on whether they think it's an answer). Moderators opinions' are inluenced by other users (if an answer gets several downvotes or flags then I for one am more likely to delete that answer).

I'm inclined to delete, not 'bad' answers, but rather answers which don't answer/address the question.

Furthermore "trusted" (i.e. high-reputation) users can [vote to delete](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) an answer that has been downvoted.

An alternative is to downvote (a downvote means "This answer is not useful") instead of flag (and flag when it's truly not an answer, e.g. if it's a reply addressing some other answer, which should have been posted as a comment, or something like that).