# How and when to flag an answer?

Tags: support, moderation, proposed-faq, flagging

You can "flag" an answer for moderator intervention. What are the flags, and which flag should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The available/predefined reasons for flagging are:

- **spam**

  See also [How to not be a spammer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)
- **rude or abusive**

  People are usually polite and moderate, friendly, on this site.

  But a post may be considered "rude or abusive" if it explicitly criticises and names another user, or a different school of Buddhism or even a teacher or public figure. Generally the questions on this site don't ask you to criticise others -- so, you can answer without doing that.
- **not an answer**

  This is for text which don't even try to answer to question, for example ...

  > I've had this problem too. Does anyone else have an answer?

  ... or ...

  > I don't understand this question!
- **very low quality**

  This is for answers like ...

  > lol, yes of course!

  ... or ...

  > Of course you should, why wouldn't you?

  See also [this meta-answer](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1920/254) about what type of answer is conventional on this site.

---

Note:

- **wrong answers**

  Flagging is probably **not** applicable to answers which you consider wrong or untrue -- i.e. which are answers, but which you disagree with or consider "not useful".

  Instead you may **vote down** this kind of answer (instead of flagging it).

  When you flag an answer you are asking a moderator to delete it (or perhaps to edit it if it's rude or abusive). But moderators aren't supposed to delete an answer for being wrong or untrue, so just downvote this kind of answer instead of flagging.
  I think that means it's normal on SE for a few "wrong" answers to be left on the site -- but they should be downvoted.
- **irrelevant or off-topic answers**

  Sometimes an answer fails to address the topic of the question. If so I think that might be flagged as "not an answer".

  This is also true if a question uses a tag like [theravada](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theravada) to ask a question specific to that school, and an answer is based on doctrine of a different school.
- **non-Buddhist answers**

  This is the Buddhism.SE site so answers should be based on Buddhist doctrine and/or practice.

  Answers based on other religions would be off-topic on this site, and should be deleted.

  This is also true of a few answers which are based on "science" -- e.g. physics etc. -- not that Buddhism is anti-scientific, but people are asking questions about Buddhism not about science.

Comment: Wrong answers are not Buddhist answers per definition. If you can't judge what is wrong view then how can you judge what is a Buddhist and what is not a Buddhist answer. These policies are trash, obviously moderators just want to censor some people by branding their answers as 'non-buddhist' but at the same time on record claim that this site is for all self-proclaimed Buddhists and for all Buddhist sects, even those that are heretic. This is a double standard and garbage policy.

Comment: When we look at cases where this is actually enforced, it is clear that mideration policy is anti-scientific and judgemental af. You censor based on expression, you don't censor based on meaning.

Comment: If an answer is based on Christian doctrine, for example quotes the Christian bible, then I think it's probably off-topic as an answer on this site. That's probably also true if it claims to be based on someone's speculating about quantum mechanics or astrophysics. Occasionally too someone asks a school-specific question, in which case answers based on a different school of Buddhism are off-topic.

Comment: You should make a list of forbidden words because clearly that's what is the qualifying criteria for having answers deemed "non-buddhist". Just make a rule stating that answers must comply with your standards for expression. I am serious, if you censor based on expression but not based on meaning you should make a list.

Comment: It doesn't happen often. I see you too are a veteran of the "infinity" topic about six months ago. [Your answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/36830/254) (like a few others, including mine) was deleted. Yours was talking about "conservation laws" and "comparing infinities".

Comment: Many if not most of the answers on this site contradict eachother, you clearly just want to censor what you and or Andrei disagree with. Nobody asked for this censorship, we need new mods that don't discriminate and censor what they disagree with or can't understand.

Comment: Andrei is master censorar, only posts 'experience based' "wisdom" and deletes anything including the word 'soul' no matter context.

Comment: Trash policy, double standards and blatant hypocrisy... Shamefully anti-science, anti-knowledge and anti-texts known to be true.

Comment: @MAGA2020 Reviewing Andrei's moderation history it seems to me that he's deleted three questions and zero answers in the last six months -- and so, at a minimum it seems that whatever you're talking about hasn't been a frequent problem. If you disagree with any specific moderator decision you can always post that as a topic for discussion on Meta (use e.g. `specific-question` or `specific-answer` tag). I can't guarantee in advance that I'll agree with you but let's see. IMO the moderation on this site is already very light/permissive.

Comment: I was under the impression that he deleted some christian answer recently but it might've been you or it might've been a question.  Fwiw you also recently deleted an answer based on Robert Lanza's stuff saying "it's not obviously Buddhist", well Robert Lanza gave talks at a [zen mefitation center](http://www.hazymoon.com/a-conversation-with-dr-robert-lanza-audio-talks-given-at-hazy-moon/) I think you are way out of line with these policies and censorship based on personal opinion. QM has been used to explain Buddhism and i can point to monks who have done it. You are way out of line.

Comment: [Bhikkhu Samahita on QM and Buddhism](https://youtu.be/1M2tj4S4j4I) I don't get it why you take it upon yourself to censor this type of expression and tell people that Buddhism stops where science begins and where they do and do not overlap? I think this is completely unjust and very harmful.

Comment: You totally have the burden of proof if you want to censor science based answers claiming they aren't buddhist. Who gave you that authority to decide what is and isn't Buddhism? It is extremely abusive and offensive.

Comment: Deleting that Robert Lanza based answer you are censoring speech approved by the Zen center whilst claiming this site is for all Buddhists. I think you are completely out of line...

Comment: You're referring to [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/39882/254) (which I read as an example of [Quantum mysticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mysticism)).

Comment: Stop abusive moderation practices, ktnxbye.

Comment: I don't care if it's nonsense, i want moderator's judgement to be kept suspended as it's supposed to be. I consider most posts here to be wrong, i think most posters are more or less clueless but i want them to have the right to express their views as they see fit because I want to express myself as i see fit.

Comment: Moderators aren't elected to police what is Buddhism and what isn't Buddism. When you ban "non-buddhist" expression, you are here telling us what is and isn't Buddhism, expecting the community to conform to your preconceived notilns of what Buddhism is and how to explain it. No thank you.

Comment: This is not your personal virtual temple where you are the guru, this is a place for people of all Buddhist schools, traditions and interpretations. People can express themselves and their possibly wrong views however and that in whatever terms they see fit as long as they are not abusive. Stop this abusive moderation ktnxbye. Also undelete those math answers and when are we gonna have moderator elections?

Comment: ... and as long as they respect the Q&A format -- keep their answers "on-topic" -- avoid "extended discussion" (except in chat or on Meta) ...

Comment: *and as long as they respect the Q&A format -- keep their answers "on-topic"* sure. I am having problem with the general ban on scientific answers not the off-topic content.

Comment: *"This is also true of a few answers which are based on "science" -- e.g. physics etc."* being based on this or that doesn't make it off-topic, people can answer in whatever terms they want.

Comment: I don't want to spend more time making my case here, if you want to continue with this abuse then whatever. I don't even care as i hardly ever run into these problems but i wanted to point out the inconsistency in these policies. As far as i am concerned id vote for sutta only policy for answers but i still do not like seeing abusive moderation, discrimination and double standards.

Comment: I don't think I'm anti-science FWIW -- I studied almost nothing but Physics and Maths at school, and little except quantum mechanics and astrophysics at university. I don't think this is the right site to discuss QM -- making vague assertions using the vocabulary of QM is off-topic IMO -- especially when the OP's question is asking about the doctrine of a specific school.

Comment: And if anyone posts nonsense about Buddhism then that isn't great either but at least that's on-topic here -- so that post's quality can in theory, according to SE's model be evaluated by the subject matter experts in the user community -- and therefore can be downvoted instead of flagged.

Comment: It's not personal, i think the policy is anti-scientific and anti-texts known to be true (mathematics or texts describing experiments). Many Buddhists obviously like scientific expression as is evident by The Great Five (answers deleted by Andrei).  The notion of infinity is one and the same and mathematicians have spent much effort to understand and express it, it is unreasonable to assume that Buddhist notion of infinity is somehow non-compliant or can not be rightly explained in similar terms.

Comment: As far as i am concerned 5 Buddhists gave 5 answers and 1 guy due to disagreement deleted them all and now we can't have nice things.

Comment: *And if anyone posts nonsense about Buddhism then that isn't great either* unfortunately most of the content here is non-sense imo. It can't be any other way tho because counterfeit Dhamma is allowed here. It doesn't bother me but i am surprised how people who are obvious beginners answer most questions thinking they have something useful to say.

Comment: Id be even more tolerant and let people downvote what they don't like, if someone wants to start a neo christian buddhist sect complete with a quantum mechanics theory, i don't care because ie both me and contradictory Andrei are allowed to post so why not allow whatever.